# I am getting this error: 'TypeError: callback is not a function', but the function is still executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, axios

I am getting 'TypeError: callback is not a function when trying to execute a function.

My code:

```
const api = require('axios');

getData(printData);


async function getData(callback) {
  try {
    const results = await api.get('https://sampleurl.com//wp-json/api/data');
    const dataArray = results.data.items;
    callback(dataArray);
  } catch (err) {console.error(err)}
}

function printData(data) {
  console.log('Got data:', data.length);
}

module.exports = getData();
```

I am getting this response in the console:

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at getLabiExams (/backend/src/scrapers/xxx/getData.js:10:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
Got data: 698
```

Notice that the function is still working properly, although it is returning the 'callback is not a function' error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe `module.exports = getData;`  instead of `module.exports = getData();` ? By adding parentheses, you export the result of getData, instaed of the getData method

Comment: Remove parentheses from `module.exports = getData();`. When you put them, the function invokes.

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = getData();
```

You are accidentally calling your function over here. Since no arguments are passed to it at this point, `callback` is undefined, and so is not a function.

Comment: Exactly that! Thank you a lot